# Javascript how to adding minus number and positive number

Tags: javascript, numbers, cpu-word

i made a simple program convert number to word. and i got problem when i want to convert minus number.

I want to find the index in the array 'satuan' so that later I add the word 'minus'

in my code i use Indonesian language btw.

js code:

```
// i have array like this
var satuan  = ['', 'satu', 'dua', 'tiga', 'empat', 'lima', 'enam', 'tujuh', 'delapan', 'sembilan'];

// and my function to convert minus number like this
function convert_minesPuluhan(num) {
  var c = Math.abs(num) + Math.abs(num);
  if (num < 0 && num > -10) {
    return satuan[num + c];
  }
}
```

but when i console.log(num + c). the result is (example the num value is -1) -12.

[image: see picture]

but what I want is -1 + 1 + 1 = 1

```
// so i want like this
satuan[1];
```

how to solve this?

Comment: When I add `console.log(convert_minesPuluhan(-1));` to your script, the output is `satu` (which I think is what you want)...

Comment: How would 2 absolute values added together be less than `0`, ever? Just use Array notation to get Array elements. If you just want negative to be positive `if(num < 0){satuan[Math.abs(-1)]`.

Comment: Can anyone explain why -ve number needs to be converted in this way? Simply multiplying it with -1 should solve the problem right? Or is there any purpose to it.

Comment: `function convert_minesPuluhan(num){ let n = num < 0 ? Math.abs(num) : num; return satuan[n]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting a string for `num`

So, you'll have to do `num = parseInt(num)` first to convert it into an int datatype.

i.e.

```
function convert_minesPuluhan(num) {
  num = parseInt(num)
  var c = Math.abs(num) + Math.abs(num);
  if (num < 0 && num > -10) {
    return satuan[num + c];
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? in js when you do "-1"+2 you get "-12" (string concatenation happens), so you'll have to convert it into a number datatype first. `num` is just a variable he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your code is working fine. I understand that you need to add the 'minus' keyword before negative numbers.

```js
var satuan  = ['', 'satu', 'dua', 'tiga', 'empat', 'lima', 'enam', 'tujuh', 'delapan', 'sembilan'];

// and my function to convert minus number like this
function convert_minesPuluhan(num) {
  var c = Math.abs(num) + Math.abs(num);

  if (num < 0 && num > -10) {
    console.log("minus " + satuan[num + c])
    return "minus " + satuan[num + c];
  }
}

convert_minesPuluhan(-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the input of your function to integer

You are  adding 2 strings in your function "-1" and "2" and thats why youre getting "-12" which is undefined.

```
let num = parseInt(num);
```

Try this inside your function and rest all is the same.